# How to set dynamic domain for many2one field without onchange trigger?

Tags: odoo

I have a class in module

```py
class CRMProjects(models.Model):
    _name = 'crm.projects'
    product_lines = fields.Many2many('crm.project.product.lines')
```

and a class in another module

```py
class CoRG(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
     project = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="crm.projects")
     product_lines = fields.Many2one('crm.project.product.lines')
```

the first module has a button that opens new form from the second module and easily set dynamic domain on product_lines triggered by an `onchange`

```py
domain = {'product_lines': [('id', 'in', self.project.product_lines.ids)]}
```

the problem is that if I go to the screen of records created from that form and edit the project_lines, the domain won't work
I tried to use

```py
domain:lambda self:[('id', 'in', self.project.product_lines.ids)]
```

in the field of the 2nd module but this didn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set domain since the fields are related.

Change the as following:

```
class CoRG(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

     project = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="crm.projects")
     product_lines = fields.Many2one(related='project.product_lines')
```

Answer (score 0):

Abdulrahman

You can set the default domain on `many2one` field like this,no need to trigger `onchange`

```
@api.model
def _default_tax_group(self):
    return self.env['account.tax.group'].search([], limit=1)
tax_group_id = fields.Many2one('account.tax.group', string="Tax Group", default=_default_tax_group, required=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: still the same https://imgur.com/ScTV50G

https://imgur.com/gCTmYhs

Comment: on the search you have to add the domain which can filter the record that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue using the following implementation

```py
test1 = fields.Many2many('crm.project.product.lines', related='project.product_lines')
product_lines = fields.Many2one('crm.project.product.lines', domain="[('id', 'in', test1)]")
```

Thanks for your suggestions.